# how long is a message id in a telegram valid?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Im writing telegram bot. Every day user will get a gift and one message will be deleted. I need to know will any error occurr if I delete the message by id more than a day later. And also this question for chat.id. Is it permanent value for chat or not?

I read telegram docs and couldn’t find information about it

Answer (score 0):

A message id won't change. Your bot can delete his own messages 1 day later without a problem.

Chat id's also won't change, unless you convert a group to a supergroup, then it will change only once into the new supergroup range.